# no cors config not working with json-server

Tags: cors, json-server

I'm using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to create a mock API of my actual API for offline testing purpose.
I can see the mock API response under their Url endpoint:
`localhost:5001/api/searchresults/*`

but on my app I cannot see the results because the request is blocked by CORS.
Reading the json-server docu, there is a way to disable CORS issues, adding `jsonServer.defaults({ noCors: true })` as middleware.

I than add a custom server and run this with node server.js

```
// server.js
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults({ noCors: true })

server.use(middlewares)

server.use('/api/searchresults', router)
server.listen(5001, () => {
  console.log('Mock api server listening at localhost:5001')
})
```

but unfortunately I still get cors issues when try to fetch my data.

Anyone has an idea why is not working or how to address this problem?

Here is the full project: https://github.com/ElliotForWater/efw-webapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems that the json-server package is not mantained anymore
https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1219
I figured out a way to fix it with just Express

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
  next()
})
```

Adding those lines worked for us
I hope can be helpful for someone else in similar situation

Comment: where did you add those lines?

Comment: Put them in server.js or whatever your node script is called. The one where you'd have a `const server = express();`

Comment: What is the node script?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to enable CORS is with the cors library.

install it in your project with `npm install cors`, then require it and add it as a middleware:

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
    
// Import the library:
const cors = require('cors');

const server = jsonServer.create()       
        
// Then use it before your routes are set up:
server.use(cors());
```

By default, the cors library will allow requests from any origin. This can open you up to security problems and abuse.

For production use, it’s best not to allow all origins. Instead, create a `domainList` of allowed domains, and check each request against the `domainList`. Here’s how:

```
// Set up a domainList and check against it:
const domainList = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']

const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (domainList.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  },
}

// Then pass them to cors:
server.use(cors(corsOptions));
```